# Inno setup : Adding third party reference in the .net dll not working

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am using .net class library as dll in my inno script.
I have added SSH.Net as third party reference in class library for connecting to SFTP.

```
[Code]
function DownloadFile(host: WideString; port: Integer; path: WideString; user: WideString; password: WideString; outputhPath: WideString; out message: WideString): Boolean;
external 'DownloadFile@files:InnoPlugin.dll stdcall';
```

In normal case it works fine but When I use any method or class of ssh.net in my function it gives External Exception.

My project's platform target is set to x86.

Can't we include any extra third party reference?

Comment: Calling Init(); before my function is not seems working for me.

Comment: Thanks @MartinPrikryl It was my silly mistake not including additional dll in external clause.